# MySQL .NET connector - Get table that column belongs to?

Tags: .net, asp.net, mysql

I am going through all the columns of a row's table's columns (that was a tricky way of saying it - basically I have a row "R", where I use R.Table.Columns to iterate through them).

For each column, I would like to know which table it belongs to.

However, with the following query, only 1 table appears in the resultset. How come? I need to distinguish between the different tables, even if the column names are the same.

```
SELECT * FROM User LEFT OUTER JOIN Provider ON User.ProviderID=Provider.ID WHERE User.IsDeleted=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliases:

```
SELECT 
 table1.column1 AS foo,
 table2.column1 AS bar,
 ...
```

Using SELECT * is bad practice anyway: [SELECT * is evil](http://www.parseerror.com/sql/select%2aisevil.html)

Comment: It's not evil in my case. I need to use it for ORM purposes.

Comment: Even with your suggestion, TableName of the column returns "Table". In other words, it's not working at all.

Comment: @piotrpo you are generalizing. ORM is good for some purposes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'TableName of the column returns "Table"' or why this should not work

Comment: In your example, given the DataColumn object for table1.column1, I would like to get the name "table1". However, if I look at the DataColumns Table, it's a table that has the TableName property set to "Table".

Answer (score 0):

You should strongly consider using the [show tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-tables.html) and [show columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-columns.html) commands for database discovery

You can then generate queries from that and avoid using `select *`

To awnser your question more directly, i dont think its possible to get the table name for a column in a result set since those columns doent have to come from a table at all. Consider this completely valid query for example:

```
select 'foo' as bar, 1+1 as result;
```